# How to update progressbar at 10 percent increments?

Tags: android

I have a service running that uploads photos. Currently it's updating the progressbar every one percent. 1%...2%..3%...

How would I update it only at increments of 10%?

```
 @Override
        public void writeTo(@NonNull BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
            long fileLength = mFile.length();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(mFile);
            long uploaded = 0;
            int read;

            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                int percent = (int) (100 * uploaded / fileLength);

                //Update progress bar
                mManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, uploadingProgressNotification(String.valueOf(current_image_uploading), percent));
                uploaded += read;
                sink.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }



        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this piece of code

```
int percent = 10 * (int) (10 * uploaded / fileLength);
```

dividing by 10  and casting to int will discard the decimal place for the digits.
you then multiply it by 10 to give you increments in steps of 10s.